# Change datacontext using a trigger on radiobutton

Tags: wpf, triggers

I'm trying to move two existing views into one common view in WPF.
The GUI is identical for the two, but backend handling of the data is slightly different.

Therefore I thought I could just reuse the existing viewmodels and choose which one to use based on selection in the GUI.

[image]

The GUI is a custom user control with a property

```
public ICommand SaveRemarkCommand
```

Which is bound to the submit button.
Depending on the selected radiobutton (1 or 2), the command in the different viewmodel should be called.

Basically what I want to do is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Remarks.EnterRemarkView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Client.Controls"
         xmlns:client="clr-namespace:Client"
         Name="Root">

<StackPanel x:Name="Base" Width="320" >
    <controls:MyStandardLabel IsRequiredLabel="True" Foreground="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextForegroundBrush}"
                                  Content="{Binding Header, ElementName=Root}" />

    <controls:MyTextBox Height="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20"
                            MinLines="8" MaxLines="8" ShowUnderlines="False" Watermark="[TYPE HERE]"
                            Text="{Binding Remark, ElementName=Root, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <controls:MyStandardLabel IsRequiredLabel="False" Foreground="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextForegroundBrush}"
                                  Content="Assign remark to" />
     <controls:MyRadioButton x:Name="X" GroupName="RemarkType" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="1">
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="DataContext" Value="ViewModel1" />
                </Trigger>
    </controls:MyRadioButton>
    <controls:MyRadioButton x:Name="Y" GroupName="RemarkType" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="2">
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="DataContext" Value="ViewModel2" />
                </Trigger>
    </controls:MyRadioButton>   

    <controls:MyConfirmShortcutButton HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="20,5"
                                          Content="SUBMIT" IsDefault="True"
                                          Command="{Binding SaveRemarkCommand, ElementName=Root}" /> 
    </StackPanel>
```

I have tried a number of ways to accomplish this but with no success. Can anyone guide me on this?
(I'm aware that the code does not work, but it's a simplified description of what I want to achieve)

Comment: This looks odd. A UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Besides that, the Setters will now just set the DataContext to a string.

Comment: In order to change the UI of a single element, use a ContentControl and assign different Content values. For each possible type of Content, declare a DataTemplate with an appropriate DataType in a ResourceDictionary, e.g. Window.Resources. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: What's the actual `DataContext` of the `UserControl`? Add two commands to it and then decide which one to execute depending on which radiobutton is checked.

Answer (score 0):

if your view models have default constructors without parameters, you can create an instance of each view model and store it in Resources:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Remarks.EnterRemarkView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Client.Controls"
         xmlns:client="clr-namespace:Client"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Client.ViewModels"
         Name="Root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
         <vm:ViewModel1 x:Key="vm1"/>
         <vm:ViewModel2 x:Key="vm2"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

then in Trigger use StaticResource for Value, e.g.:

```
<Setter TargetName="Root" Property="DataContext" Value="{StaticResource vm1}" />
```

be aware that "UserControl set its own DataContext" - approach has limitations. DataContext is usually inherited from ancestor in visual tree hierarchy.

if your view models don't have default constructors, then you will have to resolve them somewhere higher in hierarchy, and also set UserControl.DataContext on higher level, e.g. in Window